# SpringBoot OAuth2 Client Google RequestMapping not working in RestController

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, request-mapping

I am trying to build a SpringBoot OAuth2 Application but stuck with initiating the next POST request of access_token.

This is my code  https://github.com/sangeeta-p-shetty/springboot_oauth2_google.git

It runs on http://localhost:8080/security. Currently it successfully redirects to Google and on Sign In redirects to the Redirect URL

Primarily, I am stuck at 3 areas:

1. @RequestMapping in @RestController is not working.
2. As RequestMapping is not working, the sample code even though successfully authorizes I am not able to initiate the next POST request of AccessToken. Wanted guidance on how to capture the response from Google and initiate a new request.
3. I wanted to redirect to OAuth2 only if specific URL is hit in the application. Currently Redirection is happening by launch of context. i.e http://localhost:8080/security

SecurityConfig.java

```
package com.google.config;    
import ....;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http 
         // only disable these during testing or for non-browser clients
            .cors().disable()
            .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .oauth2Login()
              .loginPage("/oauth2/authorization/google")
              .authorizationEndpoint()
              .authorizationRequestResolver(
                new CustomAuthorizationRequestResolver(
                  clientRegistrationRepository(), "/oauth2/authorization"));
    }
    
}
```

application.yml

```
server:
  port: 8080
  servlet:
    context-path: /security
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          google:
            client-id: test.apps.googleusercontent.com
            client-secret: test
            redirect-uri: http://localhost:8080/security/welcome.html
            authorize-uri: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth
            scope: email
            response-type: code
            cookie-path-domain: /
            cookie-secure: true
        provider:
          google:
            issuer-uri: https://accounts.google.com
```

SpringBootApplication class

```
package com.google;
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan("com.google")
public class OidcExampleApp {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(OidcExampleApp.class, args);
    }
    
}
```

AppController.java

Currently in the github code, this class is not included. But below is the intended code which does not seem to get called.

```
package com.google.controller;
import ...;
@RestController
public class AppController {
        
    @RequestMapping(value="/welcome") // here even If I give value="/welcome.html") it does not work
    public String getHi() {
        System.out.println("End Point hit*************************************");
        return "Hi";
    }
    
}
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    
        <groupId>com.codetinkering</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-oauth2-oidc-google</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <name>oauth2-example</name>
        <packaging>war</packaging>
        <parent>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.1</version>
        </parent>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
                <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
                <version>4.4.13</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
                <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
                <version>4.5.13</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    
        <build>
            <finalName>security</finalName>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                    <mainClass>com.google.OidcExampleApp</mainClass>
                </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </project>
```

Logs Screenshot

[image: OAuth Redirect and Response Log Screenshot]

Comment: Here is some initial feedback. If you only want to redirect for certain endpoints, then you should only require authentication for those endpoints. Currently the configuration specifies `.anyRequest().authenticated()` meaning that any request will redirect in order to authenticate. Next, it looks like `AppController` is not annotated with `@RestController` which is likely why it's not being picked up. I suggest you start with those items and then simplify your application as much as possible so that it's clear where the issue is originating.

Comment: my mistake of not adding @RestController while pasting here. In my original code it was there but still the problem persists. Also could you please guide me with the code in my configure method to redirect only if security/index.jsp is clicked

Comment: @EleftheriaStein-Kousathana Thanks for pointing out on the anyRequest. I was able to resolve my issue by changing it to   .authorizeRequests(
      authorize -> authorize.antMatchers("/secured/**").authenticated().anyRequest().permitAll())
    .oauth2Login().authorizationEndpoint()
    .authorizationRequestResolver(new CustomAuthorizationRequestResolver(clientRegistrationRepository(),
      "/oauth2/authorization"));